# Changing longtext format SQL

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I need some help, I have the Wordpress table "wp_postmeta", that contains 4 columns "meta_id", "post_id", "meta_key" and "meta_value".

> "meta_key" -> varchar
>
> "meta_value" -> longtext

The thing is: I have some rows with the content

`meta_key = "limit_date"`

That returns me rows with a date in dd/mm/yyyy format, and I will like to transform this data in yyyy/mm/dd

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE meta_key="limit_date"
```

Returns me all the rows I need to change, and I have tried some queries with CONVERT function, actually I´m close to get "psycho" and my low sql knowledges are dissapearing by moments... Any orientation ? Any help? Maybe I need to go for another coffee? Maybe I am looking for something that is not even possible...

Comment: have you tried or used  the DATE_FORMAT() function of mysql  ?

Comment: @HassanALi yeah I tried, but don´t worry I have done it, by using PHP and getting all the rows, formatting latter the text and updating those rows

Comment: Please Also post your answer here .Thanks

Comment: @HassanALi sure, I´m on my way

Answer (score 0):

I wasn´t able to find a solution just with SQL, so I used php, for get all the results, after that I formated the result in the Right way, and then updated the table, I´m sure there are some faster ways to do It, but this one worked for me

```
$link =new mysqli("localhost","user","passw","ddbb");
if($link->connect_error){
    die("Not connected");
}
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM wp_postmeta
        WHERE meta_key='fecha_inicio'";

$result = $link->query($sql);

$update;
$aux=0;
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $update[$aux][0]=$row['meta_id'];
        $update[$aux][1]=$row['post_id'];
        $update[$aux][2]=$row['meta_key'];
        $update[$aux][3]=$row['meta_value'];
        $aux++;
    }
}else{
    echo "0 rows";
}
print_r($update);

$aux=0;
foreach($update as $row){
    $aux2=$row[3];


    $aux3="";
    if(strlen($aux2)>0){
        $aux3 = substr($aux2,-4);
        $aux3 .= "/";
        $aux3 .= substr($aux2,-7,2);
        $aux3 .= "/";
        $aux3 .= substr($aux2,-10,2);
    }


    $update[$aux][3]=$aux3;
    $aux++;
}

foreach($update as $row){
    $sql = "UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value='".$row[3]."' WHERE meta_id=".$row[0].";";
    echo "<h1>".$sql."</h1></br></br></br>";
    if ($link->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . $link->error;
    }
}


$link->close();`
```